# Is there a jQuery based light box that meets all of my requirements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox, modal-dialog

Ive used a ton of different lightbox scripts from ones ive written myself to widely used ones but i cant seem to find one that meets all of my requirements

So far Ive given colorbox and slimbox2 a close look but each one lack a different feature that i need. I've also looked at a few others but they have lacked even more than these two.

- Must have typical Lightbox2 effect - ie. animating expand/contract of dimensions as each photo is loaded.
- Must support multiple images and navigating through those images in the modal (prev/next)
- Must support options for minimum height/width OR have a hard limit to the size of viewport
- Must have title bar or event hooks where i could inject in a title bar
- Must be able to invoke the window from code passing in the collection of image data. The images or anchors pointing to them will not be in the DOM at all. This is actually loading a sub-gallery of images that correspond to a "splash" image that is in a [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) slideshow. (see usage example)

Usage example:

```
$('#supersized a[href]').click(function(e){
   /*
    * href is something like: 
    * gallery.php?gallery=parentGallery/subGallery
    */
   e.preventDefault();
   $.getJson($(this).attr('href'), function(json){
      $.thelighboxfunc(json.images);
   };
});
```

Comment: Why don't you roll your own or just extend slimbox?  That seems like a fair solution based on your requirements.

Comment: Time constraints prevent rolling my own. Extending Slimbox was a thought, but it also comes with higher risk than finding something thats proven as-is. That may be the only option though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we decided to impose maximum dimension requirements or the content creators. This removed the maxHeight/maxWidth requirement from the lightbox library and we were then able to go with Slimbox2.

Answer (score 1):

Use Colorbox by Jack Moore http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: As i said in my post I tried Colorbox (it a Slimbox came the closest to what i need actually) but it doesnt seem to support multiple images when invkicking through the static api like `$.colorbox(options)` or at least its not documented and it didnt seem to work when i did `$.colorbox([{href: '/image1.jpg'},{href: 'image2.jpg'}]);` Does it support something like this? I may jsut be doing it wrong.

Comment: What do you mean through a static api?

Comment: I mean that the images i want to load into the lightbox do not have direct links or thumbnails within the DOM. They MUST be loaded directly into the lightbox so by static api i mean calling it like `$.colorbox(hashOrArrayOfImages, options);` as opposed to `$('a[href$=.jpg]').colorbox(options);`.

Comment: Can't you just ajax the hash of images and on success put them in a hidden div with the same rel and then use $('a[href$=.jpg]').colorbox({rel:'relValue'});

Comment: Not well. It didnt seem to want to grab the `a`'s properly when they were positioned off screen or in a hidden element. That said it might have been an issue with my implementation, i didnt work with it for very long. Given the time constraint we decided to impose a max height/width restriction on the images the client creates. Given that, Slimbox2 then met all the requirements and we used that.